# R: Bayesian package for nonlinear mixed effects model

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models, nlme, longitudinal

I'm looking for a Bayesian parallel for nonlinear mixed effects models, specifically those using the `nlme` package in R.

I've come across `blme` but that seems to be only for linear mixed-effects models. Would `brms` be appropriate in this case? I've tried to write some code that's analogous to the `nlme` construction below with the function `brm`.

```
library(nlme)
model <- nlme(height ~ exp(beta1*age + 1),
              data = Loblolly,
              fixed = list(beta1 ~ 1),
              random = list(Seed = pdDiag(list(beta1 ~ 1))),
              start = list(fixed = c(beta1 = 3)))

library(brms)
bayesian_model <- brm(bf(height ~ exp(beta1*age + 1), beta1 ~ 1, nl = TRUE), 
                      data = Loblolly,
                      prior = c(prior(normal(0, 1), nlpar = beta1)))
```

I was able to get to this point, but how exactly do I specify random effects for `beta1`? And how would I specify the diagonal variance structure like I have with `random = list(Seed = pdDiag(list(beta1 ~ 1)))`?

Comment: (1) "looking for a package" is off-topic for SO, but "trying to figure out how to do X" is on-topic, so you might want to rephrase your question slightly; (2) I would look at (a) [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_nonlinear.html) and alternately (b) the [rethinking package](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking) as an interface to Stan for this.

Comment: `rstan` is a fantastic library giving you the full power of [Stan Bayesian (hierarchical) modelling](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started). For example, `rethinking` depends on `rstan`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers In your opinion, do you think `rstan` is better than `brms` in this case? In terms of user-friendliness and available resources?

Comment: @Adrian. That really depends. In my opinion `rstan` is the more versatile option. It has a fantastic community plus google group, plus an excellent manual, online case studies, etc.  `brms` is more user-friendly for standard problems, and takes some of the low-level stuff off your hands; I believe the developers of both libraries are working closely together, and both libraries are great to work with.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I came across `stan_nlmer` http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/stan_nlmer.html, but it doesn't seem to be in the `rstanarm` package anymore?

Comment: @Adrian Interesting, I've never used the `stan_nlmer` function. I've done some fairly simple nested effects non-linear modelling in `rstan`, but always wrote my models as Stan files directly. I'm not very familiar with the `lmer` syntax and personally prefer the mathematically more intuitive notation in Stan.